# Is getter construction can exist without associated property?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, getter-setter, getter

For example, i have such code

```
get isChart(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.isTemperatureChart.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.isHypertensionChart),
    map(([isTemperatureChart, isHypertensionChart]) => isTemperatureChart || 
         isHypertensionChart)
  );
}
```

or for simplifying

```
get isChart(): boolean {
  return this.isTemperatureChart && this.isSomeOtherPropertyTrue
}
```

A long time, for me been obviously, that if I have complicated binary logic, and don't need for it any attributes from outside, I should use procedure. And just for clear code, all that times i try to use getters. But now i think, about a nature of this constructions, and can't find right answer. Is that ok, use getter just for GETTING, without associating it with some class property? Or is it not according to canons of OOP and getters/setters - only for encapsulation of class property?

Comment: Iam not sure what exactly it is that you're asking, but it is completely okay to use getters like this.

Comment: @MikeS. I'm asking right about it) Is this case of using getters - 
not contrary to the concept of oop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd example returning a primitive value is absolutely correct, but your 1st example will cause issues, because it will create a new `Observable` every time that property is queried (and with it a subscription if you are using the `async` pipe in your template). With angular, that would be every change detection cycle for that component, and for every time you query it inside your component ts.

In that case, you really should not use getters. If you want consumers to prevent overwriting the observable, and just read it, you should set the `readonly` access modifier. That will change your example to:

```
readonly isChart$: Observable<boolean> = this.isTemperatureChart.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.isHypertensionChart),
  map(([isTemperature, isHypertension]) => isTemperature || isHypertension)
);
```

<sub>Not knowing your code, but judging by the naming of your variables, it feels like you are better of using `combineLatest` instead of `withLatestFrom`</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, idk it) Just to complete question, as you think, using getters for encapsulation primitive logic, to "emmit" property, for better code - is ok?

Comment: @cyberguycyberguy that is indeed ok, and used widely. However there is a sidenote to be placed, if your typescript target is es5, the getters will be rewritten to quite a lot of code to support older browsers. So if application size is a very big priority, you should just use functions, which are transpiled to a lot less code [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEASCmIQHtoG8BQ1vQObwBdoAzZZACgEp0sc6AnQgV3oDtoBGaAak4G5a2AL4ZB0AEZh6VGnQbM2nHpzEihQA)

Comment: @PoulKruijt do you know if target es6 doesn't have that issue?

Comment: @DiegoOrtiz it still has, because it doesn't depend on it. It's about angulars change detection